# Output Parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

How do I create a report with a Stored Procedure which has an output parameter?
 The report can be developed but returning the output parameter is what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

SSRS does not support output parameters by default.

If your SP does not return any resultset, you can get the output parameters by wrapping the SP call in a regular query text:

```
DECLARE @x

EXEC dbo.YourSP @outX = @x OUTPUT

SELECT @x
```